# pip install module error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

hello guys i tried to install a python module called gmpy2 with `pip install gmpy2` but error occurs during wheel building

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'gmpy2' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-
prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-LpWKty/python3.6-
3.6.5~rc1=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-
protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -
D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DWITHMPFR -DWITHMPC -
I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/gmpy2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
3.6/src/gmpy2.o
In file included from src/gmpy2.c:426:0:
src/gmpy.h:252:12: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "mpfr.h"
            ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
`
`
----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
onv0x975/gmpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record /tmp/pip-izolloyr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-
build-onv0x975/gmpy2/
```

I tried both pip and pip3

Comment: maybe : http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Mpfr/3.0.0/mpfr.html/Installing-MPFR.html not sure ...

Answer (score 4):

You need to download MPFR source code and compile it. See installation manual: https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#installation

Comment: You'll need to install the GMP, MPFR, and MPC development libraries. Most Linux distributions will install all three if you install "libmpc-dev" or the equivalent.